# Deadlock in MySQL(5.7) InnoDB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, innodb, deadlock

There is a MySQL(5.7) InnoDB table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sample_table`
(
  `id`                      bigint(20)                             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status`                  varchar(63) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NEW',
  `message`                 varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci         DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_data`             json                                            DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id`               bigint(20)                                      DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_data_data`      json                                            DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_data_id`        bigint(20)                                      DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_relation_data_id` bigint(20)                                      DEFAULT NULL,
  `document_data`           json                                            DEFAULT NULL,
  `document_id`             bigint(20)                                      DEFAULT NULL,
  `import_id`               bigint(20)                                      DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_number`         varchar(63) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci          DEFAULT NULL,
  `insurance_number`        varchar(63) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci          DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_insurance_number` varchar(63) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci          DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at`              datetime(6)                            NOT NULL,
  `updated_at`              datetime(6)                            NOT NULL,
  `data_hash`               varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci         DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_sample_table_on_data_hash` (`data_hash`),
  KEY `index_sample_table_on_status` (`status`),
  KEY `index_sample_table_on_client_id` (`client_id`),
  KEY `index_sample_table_on_relation_data_id` (`relation_data_id`),
  KEY `index_sample_table_on_document_id` (`document_id`),
  KEY `index_sample_table_on_import_id` (`import_id`),
  KEY `index_sample_table_on_customer_number` (`customer_number`),
  KEY `index_sample_table_on_insurance_number` (`insurance_number`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1307766
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;
```

And when 2 SQL statements run at the same time, a deadlock occurs:

```sql
DELETE FROM `sample_table` WHERE `sample_table`.`id` = 1
```

```sql
UPDATE `sample_table` SET `sample_table`.`client_id` = 906991
WHERE `sample_table`.`customer_number` IS NULL
AND `sample_table`.`import_id` = 4123521
AND `sample_table`.`relation_data` IS NOT NULL
```

```
D, [2023-05-26T10:02:45.913078 #31819] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  BEGIN
D, [2023-05-26T10:02:45.913501 #31818] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  BEGIN
D, [2023-05-26T10:02:45.916714 #31819] DEBUG -- :    (3.3ms)  UPDATE `sample_table` SET `sample_table`.`client_id` = 906991 WHERE `sample_table`.`customer_number` IS NULL AND `sample_table`.`import_id` = 4123521 AND `sample_table`.`relation_data` IS NOT NULL
D, [2023-05-26T10:02:45.916448 #31818] DEBUG -- :    (2.7ms)  DELETE FROM `sample_table` WHERE `sample_table`.`id` = 1
3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:151:in `_query': Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (ActiveRecord::Deadlocked)
    from 3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:151:in `block in query'
 ...
    from single_file.rb:71:in `block in test_bug'
    from single_file.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in test_bug'
    ...
```

I prepared a rails bug executable file - https://gist.github.com/mariusz-blaszczak/6ae49e45032300635504ff2838d73d3a (but it does not occur 100% times)

Here you can find result of `show engine innodb status;`

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-05-26 08:16:27 0x40c64c3700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 27613, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 43, OS thread handle 278876960512, query id 299 172.17.0.1 root updating
UPDATE `sample_table` SET `sample_table`.`client_id` = 906991 WHERE `sample_table`.`customer_number` IS NULL AND `sample_table`.`import_id` = 4123521 AND `sample_table`.`relation_data` IS NOT NULL
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1122 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `mvp_dev`.`sample_table` trx id 27613 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 19; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000006bdc; asc     k ;;
 2: len 7; hex 25000001550557; asc %   U W;;
 3: len 3; hex 4e4557; asc NEW;;
 4: SQL NULL;
 5: SQL NULL;
 6: SQL NULL;
 7: SQL NULL;
 8: SQL NULL;
 9: SQL NULL;
 10: SQL NULL;
 11: SQL NULL;
 12: SQL NULL;
 13: SQL NULL;
 14: SQL NULL;
 15: SQL NULL;
 16: len 8; hex 99b032c081074b30; asc   2   K0;;
 17: len 8; hex 99b032c0840683f8; asc   2     ;;
 18: SQL NULL;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 27612, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 44, OS thread handle 278204790528, query id 298 172.17.0.1 root updating
DELETE FROM `sample_table` WHERE `sample_table`.`id` = 1
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1122 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `mvp_dev`.`sample_table` trx id 27612 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 19; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000006bdc; asc     k ;;
 2: len 7; hex 25000001550557; asc %   U W;;
 3: len 3; hex 4e4557; asc NEW;;
 4: SQL NULL;
 5: SQL NULL;
 6: SQL NULL;
 7: SQL NULL;
 8: SQL NULL;
 9: SQL NULL;
 10: SQL NULL;
 11: SQL NULL;
 12: SQL NULL;
 13: SQL NULL;
 14: SQL NULL;
 15: SQL NULL;
 16: len 8; hex 99b032c081074b30; asc   2   K0;;
 17: len 8; hex 99b032c0840683f8; asc   2     ;;
 18: SQL NULL;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1122 page no 7 n bits 72 index index_sample_table_on_customer_number of table `mvp_dev`.`sample_table` trx id 27612 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: SQL NULL;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

The question is why the deadlock occur? The where from the second query will not find the only row in the database.

Comment: All deadlocks occur because transaction 1 holds a lock that transaction 2 is waiting for, and transaction 2 holds a lock that transaction 1 is holding. You do not have any index that would really help  your first query, as all your indexes reference only one field, not combination of fields. This leads to the query trying to lock lot more rows than necessary. Try adding an index that would include all three fields in the first query and see where that leaves you.

Comment: Please delete the MySQL version of the `CREATE TABLE`.  (I don't know the translation from that syntax to the database's version.)

Comment: I did a workaround and in the UPDATE statement I first SELECT all needed ids and then run UPDATE the explicit ids. I hope this will lock only the needed rows.

Comment: Please explain why you have both an `_id` and `_data` (for client, document, etc) in this table instead of having just the `_id` in this table, and a separate table with the `_data`.

Comment: Rick James, the sample_table is an intermediate step while importing records to other tables - clients, documents, etc. So in this table, we have raw data (in _data columns) and after we import the data, we update the sample_table row with FK to the created rows in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

- You mention "WHERE `sample_table`.`id` = 1", but I don't see `id` in that table.  Furthermore, I would expect it to be (by convention) the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- This would benefit from a composite `INDEX(import_id, customer_number)`

  ```
  WHERE `sample_table`.`customer_number` IS NULL
    AND `sample_table`.`import_id` = 4123521
    AND `sample_table`.`relation_data` IS NOT NULL
  ```

**Indexes**

- An index definition cannot contain `TEXT`, `BLOG`, or `JSON` columns.
- An index work bests then the `WHERE` columns being tested with `=` (or `IS NULL`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for the ruby syntax for creating table. I updated my question with raw SQL for table creation.

Comment: Could you explain why you suggest composite index only on two columns: import_id, customer_number? Is it better somehow than having index on 3 columns in this case?

Comment: @mario199 - I added to my Answer.

Comment: Seems like the schema should have a `Relations` table that maps `relation_id` to `relation_data`.  Then a `LEFT JOIN` to that table would let you get to the data.  More importantly, `sample_table` could have `relation_id` and be `NULL` or not.  In this case, the index can (and should) be 3-column.

Comment: And, the `_data` columns would not exist in `sample_table`.